# Objective C: ResignFirstResponder with a button

Tags: objective-c, keyboard

Is there a way for a `UIButton` to trigger resignFirstResponder?
I have my program set to do so in a function when you tap outside of a textfield, but I want the keyboard to go away when the user hits the submit button.

This is what I have for the UITextFields

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [x1 resignFirstResponder];
 [x2 resignFirstResponder];
 [y1 resignFirstResponder];
 [y2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: So, x1, x2, y1, and y2 are your UITextFields? Does this submit button of yours have an action method it triggers?

Comment: Yes it does    -(IBAction)solve:(id)sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the existence of the method you mention, how about:

```
- (IBAction)solve:(id)sender {
   [x1 resignFirstResponder];
   [x2 resignFirstResponder];
   [y1 resignFirstResponder];
   [y2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```