# Hide keyboard/ resignFirstResponder forcibly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikeyboard

i'm working on an app which has a `tableView` with a `textField` in the right side of its each cell(there are more than 20 cells).
i've created custom cell's for each row except for the last one.
In the last row there is only a button.

Now i  want to call `resignFirstResponder` on the button's click.
What should i do Please help?

Comment: So, u r getting k/b on click of the textfields and u want to resign th k/b on that button click.?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to keep track of which textfield in which cell has the first responder and resign it like this.

```
[myCellTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to keep track of the text field with the keyboard.  Implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your controller, and set the controller as each of the text fields' delegates. Write the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method like so, setting an instance variable called `currentTextField`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    currentTextField = [textField retain];
}
```

Then, in your action for the button run `[currentTextField resignFirstResponder]`.

Answer (score 1):

Aopsfan's answer is probably the best solution so far. However, to add to it (as I cannot post comments), do remember to deallocate the object:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (currentTextField != nil) {
        [currentTextField release];
    }
    currentTextField = [textField retain];
}
```

Better still use @property's and @synthesize so the runtime can do the memory management for you.

**[ViewController].h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField* currentTextField;
```

**[ViewController].m**

```
@synthesize currentTextField = _currentTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad|Appear {
    self.currentTextField = nil;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [_currentTextField release], _currentTextField = nil;
    ...
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentTextField = textField;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.currentTextField) {
        [self.currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you:

[Objective C: ResignFirstResponder with a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456204/objective-c-resignfirstresponder-with-a-button)

Provide some code so that, it will be easier to help u.

Hope this helps you. :)